# TV episode about group trapped in haunted house?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I remember watching this show in the late 90's, early 00's. I don't remember the channel, but it was in the USA and English. I can only recall a few points.

1. There was a group of five or six people (all adults, male and female) trapped in this house with either ghosts or a killer chasing them
2. I don't think they all knew each other
3. Every room is pretty dark so I think it takes place at night
4. There is one scene where everybody is in this small room. One of the women (a younger white girl) takes a seat on this old table. Another woman (an older black lady) yells, "Get that pussy off the table!". The white girl jumps off, but the black lady says that she meant the (black?) **cat** that was sitting on the table as well. I believe this was supposed to be a joke.
5. I think the cat is seen again later
6. All but two of the people are killed in the house (I think the white girl was one of them to make it)
7. I think it ends with the survivors trying to get a (yellow?) car started while the ghost/killer is approaching them. I don't remember if they made it or not.
8. Points six and seven could have also been from a different episode, but I didn't watch it that much so that's doubtful
9. Now that I think about it, the whole thing may have been set in hell with the group of people being sinners or something

I'm pretty sure it was a show because I remember there was a narrator at the end that, after possibly summarizing the show's events, did say they would "see you next time". Or something to that affect. They might have also had a maniacal laugh, and might also have been sitting in a graveyard.

I'm certain it was way too adult-themed to be Goosebumps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be, at least in part, from "Tales from the Crypt: Demon Knight", which was a movie but based on an ongoing anthology show and so used many of the tropes of the show (including ending off with the Cryptkeeper making a joke about what happened and saying something along the lines of "See You Next Time!").  I can't verify all the elements, but it's always possible some of your memories might have come from different episodes or movies (especially if they played it as a marathon or something).

The "Get That Pussy off the Table" scene you recall can be seen here: